Presto + Why Metastore cache configuration not works on PrestoDB versions
we are using presto version - presto-server-350 , and we have presto cluster with 54 nodes
PrestoSQL version 350 is the last version with the PrestoSQL brand.
we want to implement the following setting on each presto node , since we suspect about Hive metastore is overloaded ,
hive.partition-versioning-enabled=true
hive.metastore-cache-scope=ALL
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=1d
hive.metastore-refresh-interval=1d
hive.metastore-cache-maximum-size=10000000

above setting comes from the doc -
https://www.alluxio.io/blog/a-deep-dive-into-caching-in-presto/#toc-1
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/13205
after we set this setting in hive.properties, on all presto nodes , then we restart the presto service in order to bring configuration will take affect
but presto doesn't start and that because the following exception from presto log
1) Error: Configuration property 'hive.partition-versioning-enabled' was not used

why presto version - 350 not support Metastore cache properties ?
if so what are the presto version that support Metastore cache properties ?

here is an example of hive.properties file ( as already mentioned  Metastore cache configuration not working and gives exception about parameter not used )
#
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://metastore_node_01.opstg.com:9083,thrift://metastore_node_03.opstg.com:9083
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
hive.parquet.fail-on-corrupted-statistics=false
hive.force-local-scheduling=true
hive.parquet.use-column-names=true
hive.max-partitions-per-scan=5900000
hive.metastore-timeout=20s
#Metastore cache configuration
hive.partition-versioning-enabled=true
hive.metastore-cache-scope=ALL
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=1d
hive.metastore-refresh-interval=1d
hive.metastore-cache-maximum-size=10000000

